# Looking for a SF anthology including a story in which humans arrive on a planet and mistake the cows for intelligent life

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

Looking for a SF anthology I had at school 1975 ish? Hard back, navy blue? Dust jacket had white square pictures??

I remember a collection of short stories, maybe including Pitch Black… but also a series of cartoons. Another story, humans arrive on a planet, mistake the cows for intelligent life, turns out the trees are the intelligent ones, and treats the human like a daisy, pulling off their limbs.

Comment: I came here expecting it to be the "Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy". Ford Prefect and Arthur talk to several cows. https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Ameglian_Major_Cow

Answer (score 13):

> humans arrive on a planet, mistake the cows for intelligent life, turns out the trees are the intelligent ones, and treats the human like a daisy, pulling off their limbs.

That sounds like Iain M.Bank's short story Odd Attachment, from the collection The State Of The Art (Which was published in 1991, but the story fits so well...).

> It was small and silver, and it walked on what might have been hind legs, or a pair of over-developed roots. It crossed to one of the grazers and started making noises at it. ...
> The silver seedlet moved to another grazer and made noises at it. Confused, the grazer broke wind. The seedlet went to the animal's rear end and started speaking loudly there.
> Fropone clapped a couple of vines together to request respectfully the silver creature's attention, and made to spread the same two leaf-palms on the ground before the seedlet, in a gesture of supplication.

...

> He took hold of one of the little pink filaments and pulled.
> It came off with a faint 'pop'. Another, muffled-sounding noise came from the silvery top of the creature.
> She loves me...

My copy of The State Of The Art (UK edition published by Orbit) has black & white artwork before each story, but I wouldn't call them cartoons. According to [ISFDB, it's been collected in a few other anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91903) but nothing about them suggests they include cartoons.

Comment: Thank you! That’s the story… My recollection is that there were a couple of sections of cartoons, not related to the stories… I’ll take a look at The State of the Art.

Comment: @HelenHooley: if that's the story please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer, below the votes counter (it will turn green)